# OpenCV imshow fails with src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'

Tags: c++, opencv

Code for operating my camera is giving me images as signed 32-bit integers, and I would like to turn this into an openCV `Mat`.

When I have 16-bit signed integers, I do the following:

```
int16_t x[100][100];
Mat A(100, 100, CV_16SC1, x);
imshow("BLAH", A);
```

This works. Similarly, when I have 8-bit unsigned integers I use `uint8_t` and `CV_8UC1` and it works. I can also use `double` and `CV_64FC1` and it works. Sadly, the following does not work:

```
int32_t x[100][100];
Mat A(100, 100, CV_32SC1, x);
imshow("BLAH", A);
```

OpenCV throws a `-215:Assertion failed` exception on the `imshow` line, indicating the `Mat` was not properly loaded in the first place (I think). I have also tried using `int` instead of `int32_t`, but to no avail.

Comment: your mat constructions look okay so that can't be it. if I had to guess, it's complaining about the element type. it wants unsigneds or floats. -- well _what_ assertion failed? "assertion failed" is insufficient. I've added the likely error message to your post as the title. -- always, complete error message. and a [mre] please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your error message for you. It says:

`/opencv/modules/highgui/src/precomp.hpp:155: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src_depth != CV_16F && src_depth != CV_32S in function 'convertToShow'`

That means `imshow` *does not* accept 32 bit signed integers (nor does it accept half floats).

You need to give it anything but that. Convert your data to one of the supported types, which are currently: `uint8`, `uint16`, `float`, `double`.

Mind the value range. For the accepted integers, it's the entire range. For floats, it's 0.0 to 1.0, that are mapped to black/white. If your values don't *use* the expected range, you *might* see an entirely black image (underexposed) or one that is mostly white (overexposed).

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for your help. Yes, that seems to do the trick. There isn't an unsigned 32-bit int, so I'll convert to something else, but other than that, great!

Comment: oh right, uint32 doesn't exist in OpenCV and they axed CV_32S for `imshow` some while ago... did not notice that! -- if you use the negative half of your signed int, I'd recommend just working with floats, and mapping 0 to be 0.5 (gray), so you see negative values as dark. if your value range isn't exceeding int16, you could just cast to that instead. for unknown value ranges, dividing by maximum would give you best visibility, or maybe even applying logarithms.